# Mock criteria count api grails/groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking

I have a problem while trying to unit test a service class api

*MyService.groovy*

```
public int myMethod() {
  def cr = MyDomain.createCriteria()

  def myDomainCount = cr.count {
    isNull("column1")
  }

  return myDomainCount
}
```

*MyTestClass.groovy*

```
class MyTestClassTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

  void testMyCount() {

    mockDomain(MyDomain)

    myCriteria = [count :{Closure cls -> 10}]
    MyDomain.metaClass.static.createCriteria = {myCriteria}

    int cnt = new MyService().myMethod()

    assert 10 == cnt
  }
}
```

Execution of above test method fails on while executing myMethod(). It fails on the line

```
cr.count {
  isNull("column1")
}
```

The stacktrace that i get during the execution :

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.MyService.isNull() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [column1]
 Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), is(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object) at
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55) at 
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78) at
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
```

Note: The same test case works fine if I use `cr.list` in both the place(service class and test class). I don't know why it fails during for count?????!!!!

Any idea would be a great help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of grails?

Comment: I am using grails 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of solving this:

### 1 - Just create instances

Since you can mock your domain class, create instances that matches your serivice query.

```
@TestFor(MyService)
@Mock(MyDomain)
class MyServiceTests {
  void testService() {
    MyDomain instance = new MyDomain(...)
    assert instance.save(flush:true)
    def count = service.myMethod()
    assert 1 == count
  }
}
```

### 2 - Mock grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder

`createCriteria()` return an instance of `grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder`, you can use the Groovy `MockFor` to change the bahavior of `count{}`.

```
@TestFor(MyService)
@Mock(MyDomain)
class MyDomainServiceTests {

  void testWithGroovyMock() {
    def mockedCriteria = new MockFor(CriteriaBuilder)
    mockedCriteria.demand.count(0..999) { Closure cls ->
      return 10
    }

    def count

    mockedCriteria.use {
      count = service.countWithIsNull()
    }

    assert 10 == count

  }

}
```

You can find more info about the Groovy MockFor [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Mocks).

Note also that I'm using the Grails 2.x way of declaring Unit Tests (annotations).

Comment: Thank you Michels... I tried the way you suggested. Below is my code

Comment: void testMyServiceMethod() {
  
  // mock the domain object
  mockDomain(MyDomain)
  
  def mockedCriteria = new MockFor(CriteriaBuilder)
     mockedCriteria.demand.count(1..1) { Closure cls ->
       return 10
     }
 
     def count
 
     mockedCriteria.use {
       count = service.myServiceMethod()
     }
 
     assert 10 == count
   
 }

Comment: I am getting the error as :                                            groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.domain.MyDomain.createCriteria() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: createCriteria()
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)

Comment: Have you changed your test to use `@TestFor` and `@Mock`? I tested here with Grails 2.2.1 and it works.

Comment: Instead of <code>@Mock</code> I used <code>mockDomain(MyDomain)</code> and extended GrailsUnitTestCase.Does that make difference. Why I did this because there are other test cases which uses mockDomain(MyDomain, [instance list]) and I use that MyDomain.list() for building some stuffs and testing some other functionality.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Michels. I changed my code accordingly to use the @Mock in all the places. Looks like it is working.

Comment: But yes I have to use @Mock instead of mockDomain(MyDomain), I dont know what is the difference in that???!!!!

Comment: @Mock will use `DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomain()` and not `GrailsUnitTestCase.mockDomain()`.